# How do I convert an int to bits?

Tags: c

Long time **READER** of the site, first question I've had to ask as I can't find an answer on here; maybe I'm not using the right search terms or I'm just trying to do it in a completely obscure way =/

I'm working with an Arduino and some LEDs forming a matrix board, and trying to get text/symbols to display on it. In order to achieve this I've mapped some digits (0 & 1 to start with) and which pixels need to come on to form them (each will be 5 high, by 3 wide). I have been trying to store these in an array as follows:

```
int displayLetters[2][4] = { // [2] = number of chars/digits contained in array, [4] = display width (3) + 1 blank column 
  {11111,10001,11111,00000}, // 0
  {01001,11111,00001,00000} // 1
};
```

I then created the following (what I thought would be a simple) function to "explode" those into an array of 0's and 1's as necessary which then gets iterated over to determine whether the LED should be on or off.

```
void convertToBits(int inputValue, int outputArray[]) {
  int i = 0;

  if (inputValue == 0) { // set all values of array to zero
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      outputArray[4-i] = 0;
    }
  } else {    
    while (inputValue > 0) {
      int digit = inputValue % 10;
      outputArray[4-i] = digit; // 4-i to prevent digits being stored in reverse order

      inputValue /= 10;
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Expecting that for `displayLetters[1][0]` I would get an array like {0,1,0,0,1}. But when it gets to `convertToBits` it's showing this as 513 (which I think is the HEX value?).

If I put the values as just `1001`, `11111` (that one works fine already), `1` and `0` (also works fine) respectively, then it behaves as expected. I'd like to keep the leading zeroes if possible for readability, but if it can't be done like that, I guess I can lose them.

I've played around with all sorts of data types, strings, uint8_t, unsigned int, etc and I can never get it to do what I need.

Any assistance greatly appreciated, and I hope I've included enough information. I've omitted the rest of the code as I deem that to be stable and behaving as expected, the issues are being caused by the `convertToBits` function / data being passed to it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Numbers with leading 0 are interpreted as octal, not decimal!
01001 (oct) == 513 (dez)

Comment: Hi tpr, thanks for the reply, I thought that might be happening but I could never pin down how to whether it was going in 8's or 16's!

Comment: Is this C or C++? Please don't say both! Looks like C.

Comment: @DanAllen Both... Haha, you are correct, it's just C - I'll correct the tags!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using C++14, you can use [binary literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) in the form:

```
int displayLetters[2][4] = {
  {0b11111,0b10001,0b11111,0b00000}, // 0
  {0b01001,0b11111,0b00001,0b00000} // 1
};
```

Otherwise you must use hexadecimal literals:

```
int displayLetters[2][4] = {
  {0x1F,0x11,0x1F,0x00}, // 0
  {0x09,0x1F,0x01,0x00} // 1
};
```

To get the bits for these 5 bit long values, we use bit operators (fun, huh?):

```
outputArray[0] = (inputValue & 0x10) ? 1 : 0;
outputArray[1] = (inputValue & 0x08) ? 1 : 0;
outputArray[2] = (inputValue & 0x04) ? 1 : 0;
outputArray[3] = (inputValue & 0x02) ? 1 : 0;
outputArray[4] = (inputValue & 0x01) ? 1 : 0;

// Or with binary literals:

outputArray[0] = (inputValue & 0b10000) ? 1 : 0;
outputArray[1] = (inputValue &  0b1000) ? 1 : 0;
outputArray[2] = (inputValue &   0b100) ? 1 : 0;
outputArray[3] = (inputValue &    0b10) ? 1 : 0;
outputArray[4] = (inputValue &     0b1) ? 1 : 0;
```

That should work nicely. :)

EDIT: Added conversion to boolean-like values.

Comment: Hi @InternetAussie, thanks for the response. Annoyingly I'd thought of using the bit operators in the middle of the night but forgot when I started up again this morning and just started where I left off last night.    I implemented your solution with the Hex approach and had a strange result, getting `168421` when converting 0x11 (dec 31, bin 11111). When I realised this was just showing that 16, 8, 4, 2 and 1, were true, I changed to the following approach and its now working! `if (inputValue & 0x10) outputArray[0] = 1;`    Thank you very much for the assistance :)

Comment: I *thought* there was something off about it. I was thinking in terms of booleans :P You're welcome :)

Comment: Nice edit to create a standalone response. I'd combatted this by initialising the contents of the original array in main() to 0 prior to the `convertToBits` function call.

Answer (score 1):

***Following is the code to convert Positive Integer to bits in C++***

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void convertIntegerToBits(int number)  {
  if(number>0)  {
    convertIntegerToBits(number>>1);
     cout<<(number&1);
  }
  return ;
}

int main()  {
  convertIntegerToBits(1024);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> convert(int x) {
  vector<int> ret;
  while(x) {
   if (x&1)
     ret.push_back(1);
   else
     ret.push_back(0);
x>>=1;  
}
reverse(ret.begin(),ret.end());
return ret;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ines - I'm struggling to see how to implement this, I've tried `int columnState[5];` and `columnState = convert("01001");` but it won't compile, giving me a few errors, including the following message: `error: 'vector' does not name a type`.

Comment: to use `std::vector` compilation should be done using `-std=c++11` flag.

Answer (score 0):

In `C` or `C++` if you start a number with `0`, the compiler reads it as `octal` number. To avoid this leave the leading zeros while declaring your `displayLetters` array.

```
void convertToBits(int inputValue, int outputArray[]) 
{
    int i = 0, width=5;
    int number = inputValue;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(inputValue>0){
            outputArray[4-i] = (inputValue%10);
            inputValue/=10;
        }
        else
            outputArray[4-i] = 0;
    }
}
```

This function will take care of `leading zeros` and width of `bit` sequence can be easily changed.

Comment: By using `%10` and `/10` you're splitting that number into individual decimal digits not bits.

Comment: @DanAllen My code was doing this too (I could witness it happily splitting the 513 into {0,0,5,1,3}, but I think it would have been acceptable in an instance where I was only dealing with 0's and 1's to create 'kinda' bits?